# more than one bluetooth adapter on RPI 2

Tags: bluetooth

Can I have more than one bluetooth adapters in a single RPI 2?

Would there be any limitation in the bluez stack?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange Community. I'm curious, what is the rationale/reasons behind this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only limitation is the amount of usb ports. The OS in your RPi will be able to handle that.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange! Can you offer any evidence that you or someone else has operated multiple BT adapters on a RPi? I would have thought that multiple adapters on the same Host would want to pair up with or otherwise mutually interfere with each other... but that is not a criticism of your answer (**I** haven't -1 you!)

Comment: It is a basic knowledge of OS's and Bluetooth protocols. Whoever did "-1" me, prove me I am wrong (or you are an idiot). Bluetooth won't mutually interfere as they are built for this. Regarding the OS, every BT dongle is just another communication port. I am just a CS graduated engineer with a hobby for electronics and networks.

Comment: Pi2 has four USB port and hence it should not be an issue I guess